# Adding image to an HTML string iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

How can i add an image present in my Xcode project in to an HTML string to take a printout of that.

I have tried the following code but the image does'nt print instead a blank box appears in the PDF.

```
-(NSString *)prepareHTMLText {
    NSMutableString *body = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"<!DOCTYPE html><html><body>"];


        [body appendString:@"<h2>Ingredients</h2>"];

     [body appendFormat:@"<p>%@ %@</p>", @"text", @"TEStText"];

   // [body appendFormat:@"<img src=\"%@\" alt=\"\" height=\"100\" width=\"100\"/>",[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"edit" ofType:@"png"]];

    [body appendFormat:@"<img src=\"%@\"/>",[UIImage imageNamed:@"edit.png"]];

    [body appendString:@"</body></html>"];
    return body;
}
```

I am getting the out put as above
[image]

Comment: get image in a string and then pass a string instead of [UIImage imageNamed:@"edit.png"];... May be it will work...

Comment: Is it working when you add <img src=\"edit.png\"/>???

Comment: Is your image name exists???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a URL, not a file path or the image object itself. Try something like:

```
NSString *fileURLString = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"edit" withExtension:@"png"] absoluteString];
[body appendFormat:@"<img src=\"%@\"/>", fileURLString];
```